# How to resize my view programmatically using autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout

I am designed my screen in xib using autolayout(xcode 6). I have to redesign the screen programmatically using autolayout.

I have 4 views in my screen horizontally. I have to hide the third view and move the fourth view to third view's position using autolayout.

How do I update the constraint programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `NSLayoutConstraint` and assign proper `IBOutlet` to any of your constraints and then where you wants to change the view size use `constant` property of `NSLayoutConstraint` to change the value.
e.g

```
in your viewController.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tempConstraint;
some where in your viewController.m
tempConstraint.constant = 50; // or what ever you want
```